Plist Error - Object is wrong type. Expected: NSDictionary Got: NSTaggedPointerString
I am trying to create a plist file but keep getting an error message.
This is the command I'm running
dscl -u username /Local/Default -mcximport /Computers/local_computer configuration.plist
Error: Object is wrong type.  Expected: NSDictionary  Got: NSTaggedPointerString
configruation.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>com.google.Chrome.extensions.ohrfgfdlbcjeddbcnla</key>
  <dict>
    <key>tenant</key>
    <string>Pri</string>
  </dict>
</dict>
</plist>

I am following this article. https://www.chromium.org/administrators/configuring-policy-for-extensions/
